# How can I get the Dashed THREE.MeshLine to work?

Tags: three.js, line

I´m trying to Use [THREE.MeshLine](https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine) to get a dashed line with thickness.

I´ve locked around for examples and put together this codepen to show what I´m trying to achieve:

[Dashed THREE.MeshLine](https://codepen.io/sergioprof/pen/MWbpWJz)

Where you see a continuos white line, I would like to get a Dashed Line.

I'm am setting up the paramenters for the material:

```
const materialX = new MeshLineMaterial({
  color: 0xffffff,
  lineWidth: 3,
  // 0 -> no dash ; 1 -> half dashline length ; 2 -> dashline === length
  dashArray: 0.1,
  // 0.5 -> balancing ; 0.1 -> more line : 0.9 -> more void
  dashRatio: 0.5    
});
```

But, even then get no Dashed Line.

**How can i get this dashed line to work?**

Any help is welcome!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that the material is transparent by specifying `transparent` to `true` when creating the `MeshLineMaterial`.

```
const materialX = new MeshLineMaterial({
  color: 0xffffff,
  lineWidth: 3,
  // 0 -> no dash ; 1 -> alf dashline length ; 2 -> dashline === length
  dashArray: 0.1,
  // 0.5 -> balancing ; 0.1 -> more line : 0.9 -> more void
  dashRatio: 0.5,
  transparent: true,
});
```

Reference: https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine/issues/66

Answer (score 0):

You can use LineDashedMaterial instead MeshLineMaterial

```
const material = new THREE.LineDashedMaterial( {
    color: 0xffffff,
    linewidth: 1,
    scale: 1,
    dashSize: 3,
    gapSize: 1,
} );
```